# Echo all months with days calendar

Tags: php, calendar, getdate

I am using the code below to echo the current month.  How can i enhance it so that is shows all the months with the names and days and dates..

Code:

```
 <?php
$today    = getdate();
$firstDay = getdate(mktime(0,0,0,$today['mon'],1,$today['year']));
$lastDay  = getdate(mktime(0,0,0,$today['mon']+1,0,$today['year']));


?>

<?php

echo '<table>';
echo '  <tr><th colspan="7">'.$today['month']." - ".$today['year']."</th></tr>";
echo '<tr class="days">';
echo '  <td>Mo</td><td>Tu</td><td>We</td><td>Th</td>';
echo '  <td>Fr</td><td>Sa</td><td>Su</td></tr>';
?> 

<?php
echo '<tr>';
for($i=1;$i<$firstDay['wday'];$i++){
    echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
}
$actday = 0;
for($i=$firstDay['wday'];$i<=7;$i++){
    $actday++;
    echo "<td>$actday</td>";
}
echo '</tr>';
?> 

<?php
$fullWeeks = floor(($lastDay['mday']-$actday)/7);

for ($i=0;$i<$fullWeeks;$i++){
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($j=0;$j<7;$j++){
        $actday++;
        echo "<td>$actday</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?> 

    <?php
    if ($actday < $lastDay['mday']){
    echo '<tr>';

    for ($i=0; $i<7;$i++){
        $actday++;
        if ($actday <= $lastDay['mday']){
            echo "<td>$actday</td>";
        }
        else {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/date or do you have any specific problems?

Comment: No problems.  This code is fine but i want all the months, not just the current one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getDates($year)
{
    $dates = array();

    date("L", mktime(0,0,0, 7,7, $year)) ? $days = 366 : $days = 365;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++){
        $month = date('m', mktime(0,0,0,1,$i,$year));
        $wk = date('W', mktime(0,0,0,1,$i,$year));
        $wkDay = date('D', mktime(0,0,0,1,$i,$year));
        $day = date('d', mktime(0,0,0,1,$i,$year));

        $dates[$month][$wk][$wkDay] = $day;
    } 

    return $dates;   
}
```

it will return an array of months->weeks->day->weekday of the year you pass to the function. Hopefully it should be easy to traverse through the array to print everything out. Am sure there are a lot of tweaks you can make to that but its a start.

I would also try and stay away from printing out html using echo, for example instead of;

```
echo '<tr>';
for($i=1;$i<$firstDay['wday'];$i++){
    echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
}
```

do;

```
<tr>;
<?php for($i=1;$i<$firstDay['wday'];$i++){ ?>
    <td><?php echo $var; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

It kind of makes the code more readable I think.

EDIT: Just thought I should include an example of a use case as well, as below:

```
<?php $dates = getDates(2011); 

$weekdays = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'); ?>
<?php foreach($dates as $month => $weeks) { ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', $weekdays); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($weeks as $week => $days){ ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($weekdays as $day){ ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo isset($days[$day]) ? $days[$day] : '&nbsp'; ?>
        </td>               
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Which gives you the output:

[image]

Comment: Just in case anyone else uses it, to make your example code work you need to set `$dates[$month][$wk][$wkDay] = $day;` instead of `$dates[$month][$wk][$day] = $wkDay;` in your function.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this function to convert entire year into array

```
  function year2array($year) {
    $res = $year >= 1970;
    if ($res) {
      // this line gets and sets same timezone, don't ask why :)
      date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get());

      $dt = strtotime("-1 day", strtotime("$year-01-01 00:00:00"));
      $res = array();
      $week = array_fill(1, 7, false);
      $last_month = 1;
      $w = 1;
      do {
        $dt = strtotime('+1 day', $dt);
        $dta = getdate($dt);
        $wday = $dta['wday'] == 0 ? 7 : $dta['wday'];
        if (($dta['mon'] != $last_month) || ($wday == 1)) {
          if ($week[1] || $week[7]) $res[$last_month][] = $week;
          $week = array_fill(1, 7, false);
          $last_month = $dta['mon'];
          }
        $week[$wday] = $dta['mday'];
        }
      while ($dta['year'] == $year);
      }
    return $res;
    }
```

Call it like

```
print_r(year2array(2011));
```

You'll see this in source (months->weeks->days):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 5
                    [4] => 6
                    [5] => 7
                    [6] => 8
                    [7] => 9
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 11
                    [3] => 12
                    [4] => 13
                    [5] => 14
                    [6] => 15
                    [7] => 16
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 17
                    [2] => 18
                    [3] => 19
                    [4] => 20
                    [5] => 21
                    [6] => 22
                    [7] => 23
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 24
                    [2] => 25
                    [3] => 26
                    [4] => 27
                    [5] => 28
                    [6] => 29
                    [7] => 30
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 31
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 3
                    [5] => 4
                    [6] => 5
                    [7] => 6
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 7
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 9
                    [4] => 10
                    [5] => 11
                    [6] => 12
                    [7] => 13
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 14
                    [2] => 15
                    [3] => 16
                    [4] => 17
                    [5] => 18
                    [6] => 19
                    [7] => 20
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 21
                    [2] => 22
                    [3] => 23
                    [4] => 24
                    [5] => 25
                    [6] => 26
                    [7] => 27
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 28
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 3
                    [5] => 4
                    [6] => 5
                    [7] => 6
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 7
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 9
                    [4] => 10
                    [5] => 11
                    [6] => 12
                    [7] => 13
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 14
                    [2] => 15
                    [3] => 16
                    [4] => 17
                    [5] => 18
                    [6] => 19
                    [7] => 20
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 21
                    [2] => 22
                    [3] => 23
                    [4] => 24
                    [5] => 25
                    [6] => 26
                    [7] => 27
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 28
                    [2] => 29
                    [3] => 30
                    [4] => 31
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 1
                    [6] => 2
                    [7] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 6
                    [4] => 7
                    [5] => 8
                    [6] => 9
                    [7] => 10
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 11
                    [2] => 12
                    [3] => 13
                    [4] => 14
                    [5] => 15
                    [6] => 16
                    [7] => 17
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 18
                    [2] => 19
                    [3] => 20
                    [4] => 21
                    [5] => 22
                    [6] => 23
                    [7] => 24
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 25
                    [2] => 26
                    [3] => 27
                    [4] => 28
                    [5] => 29
                    [6] => 30
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 5
                    [5] => 6
                    [6] => 7
                    [7] => 8
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 9
                    [2] => 10
                    [3] => 11
                    [4] => 12
                    [5] => 13
                    [6] => 14
                    [7] => 15
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 16
                    [2] => 17
                    [3] => 18
                    [4] => 19
                    [5] => 20
                    [6] => 21
                    [7] => 22
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 23
                    [2] => 24
                    [3] => 25
                    [4] => 26
                    [5] => 27
                    [6] => 28
                    [7] => 29
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 30
                    [2] => 31
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 1
                    [4] => 2
                    [5] => 3
                    [6] => 4
                    [7] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 6
                    [2] => 7
                    [3] => 8
                    [4] => 9
                    [5] => 10
                    [6] => 11
                    [7] => 12
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 13
                    [2] => 14
                    [3] => 15
                    [4] => 16
                    [5] => 17
                    [6] => 18
                    [7] => 19
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 20
                    [2] => 21
                    [3] => 22
                    [4] => 23
                    [5] => 24
                    [6] => 25
                    [7] => 26
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 27
                    [2] => 28
                    [3] => 29
                    [4] => 30
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 1
                    [6] => 2
                    [7] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 6
                    [4] => 7
                    [5] => 8
                    [6] => 9
                    [7] => 10
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 11
                    [2] => 12
                    [3] => 13
                    [4] => 14
                    [5] => 15
                    [6] => 16
                    [7] => 17
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 18
                    [2] => 19
                    [3] => 20
                    [4] => 21
                    [5] => 22
                    [6] => 23
                    [7] => 24
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 25
                    [2] => 26
                    [3] => 27
                    [4] => 28
                    [5] => 29
                    [6] => 30
                    [7] => 31
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => 3
                    [4] => 4
                    [5] => 5
                    [6] => 6
                    [7] => 7
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 8
                    [2] => 9
                    [3] => 10
                    [4] => 11
                    [5] => 12
                    [6] => 13
                    [7] => 14
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 15
                    [2] => 16
                    [3] => 17
                    [4] => 18
                    [5] => 19
                    [6] => 20
                    [7] => 21
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 22
                    [2] => 23
                    [3] => 24
                    [4] => 25
                    [5] => 26
                    [6] => 27
                    [7] => 28
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 29
                    [2] => 30
                    [3] => 31
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 1
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 3
                    [7] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                    [3] => 7
                    [4] => 8
                    [5] => 9
                    [6] => 10
                    [7] => 11
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 12
                    [2] => 13
                    [3] => 14
                    [4] => 15
                    [5] => 16
                    [6] => 17
                    [7] => 18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 19
                    [2] => 20
                    [3] => 21
                    [4] => 22
                    [5] => 23
                    [6] => 24
                    [7] => 25
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 26
                    [2] => 27
                    [3] => 28
                    [4] => 29
                    [5] => 30
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 5
                    [4] => 6
                    [5] => 7
                    [6] => 8
                    [7] => 9
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 11
                    [3] => 12
                    [4] => 13
                    [5] => 14
                    [6] => 15
                    [7] => 16
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 17
                    [2] => 18
                    [3] => 19
                    [4] => 20
                    [5] => 21
                    [6] => 22
                    [7] => 23
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 24
                    [2] => 25
                    [3] => 26
                    [4] => 27
                    [5] => 28
                    [6] => 29
                    [7] => 30
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 31
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 3
                    [5] => 4
                    [6] => 5
                    [7] => 6
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 7
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 9
                    [4] => 10
                    [5] => 11
                    [6] => 12
                    [7] => 13
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 14
                    [2] => 15
                    [3] => 16
                    [4] => 17
                    [5] => 18
                    [6] => 19
                    [7] => 20
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 21
                    [2] => 22
                    [3] => 23
                    [4] => 24
                    [5] => 25
                    [6] => 26
                    [7] => 27
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 28
                    [2] => 29
                    [3] => 30
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 1
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 3
                    [7] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                    [3] => 7
                    [4] => 8
                    [5] => 9
                    [6] => 10
                    [7] => 11
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 12
                    [2] => 13
                    [3] => 14
                    [4] => 15
                    [5] => 16
                    [6] => 17
                    [7] => 18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 19
                    [2] => 20
                    [3] => 21
                    [4] => 22
                    [5] => 23
                    [6] => 24
                    [7] => 25
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 26
                    [2] => 27
                    [3] => 28
                    [4] => 29
                    [5] => 30
                    [6] => 31
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

)
```

So, now it's easy to create month table for every month you need using something like this

```
  function month2table($month, $calendar_array) {
    $ca = 'align="center"';
    $res = "<table cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"1\" style=\"border:solid 1px #000000;font-family:tahoma;font-size:12px;background-color:#ababab\"><tr><td $ca>Mo</td><td $ca>Tu</td><td $ca>We</td><td $ca>Th</td><td $ca>Fr</td><td $ca>Sa</td><td $ca>Su</td></tr>";
    foreach ($calendar_array[$month] as $month=>$week) {
      $res .= '<tr>';
      foreach ($week as $day) {
        $res .= '<td align="right" width="20" bgcolor="#ffffff">' . ($day ? $day : '&nbsp;') . '</td>';
        }
      $res .= '</tr>';
      }
    $res .= '</table>';
    return $res;
    }
```

Use these functions like

```
  $calarr = year2array(2011);
  echo month2table(1, $calarr); // January
  echo month2table(2, $calarr); // February
  ...
  echo month2table(12, $calarr); // December
```

..or put months in `for` loop.

So... e.g. for **January 2011** in your browser you'll see this

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @JohnSmith just checked it, it works. I don't know what you have tried, but probably you did something wrong. Be aware that it's 2.5 years old, PHP has been updated a lot of times since this was originally posted, maybe you're facing some compatibility issues but from this point I can't say what's wrong on your side. It works online and local for me (have tests using two 2 different servers).

Comment: thats possible, i've got a v.uptodate php where i am now

Comment: Thank you, I've used your code (slightly modified) in a `Calendar` class and it is very handy

Comment: Works perfect and it's easy to customize, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$daysArr = array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun');
$monthtotdays= cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,date('m'),date("Y"));
$currdays=jddayofweek (cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m'),1, date("Y")) , 2 );
$currdaysval = 0;
echo "<table border=1px>";
echo "<tr>";
for($d=0;$d<=6;$d++){
echo "<td>". $daysArr[$d]."</td>";
if($daysArr[$d]==$currdays)  $currdaysval = $d;
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
if($currdaysval > 0 ){
echo '<td colspan="'.$currdaysval.'">&nbsp;</td>';
}
for($i=1;$i<=$monthtotdays;$i++){
echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
if(($i+$currdaysval )%7 <= 0 ){
echo "</tr><tr>";
}
}
echo "</tr></table>"
```

Answer (score 2):

The best answer has an inaccuracy! You should add a condition if year is leap-year BEFORE a cycle, otherwise you will have problems with output of first days of first month [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egV6O.png).

The necessary condition: `date("L", mktime(0,0,0, 7,7, $year)) ? $days = 366 : $days = 365;`
(if year is leap-year then counter of cycle = 366 else 365)

Comment: I edited the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537163/252627 above to include this change.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your current code within a function then pass an argument to it with your desired date.

Comment: i just want to echo all the months... i can't find something that can do that i see stuff related to getdate...

Comment: @AAA Can you tell me what's your specific problem?

Comment: prob is that the current code shows current month.  i want to make an online calendar so i want all the current and future months/years on the site..