# Query date for custom post type according to date in a month

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with custom post type(CPT) `good-posts`.Each posts under this CPT has  a custom field `good_date` which saves values like : YYYY-MM-DD or i.e: 2018-06-28.I a trying to creating a month calendar with posts on each day.The dates on calendar which have posts will have different colors.How can i retrieve posts for each day on calendar? DO I need to use WP_Query() for each 30 days?I think it will take a huge time.

Here is the php calendar i am following...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537163

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the posts with respective date as a query result. Then while rendering the calender check for date in result using

```
   in_array($date, $result);
```

then apply the color.if date is present in result array.